# Drawing: nodes and arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-node

Hello fellows and folks!

I need an extra help with the following picture:
[image]

Since this picture has copyrights, I found similar free icons of copyrights. 
Could you give me a hand with the nodes and arrows like in the original picture? I am really bad at doing that

Kids:

[image]

[image]

Fruits:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

MWE:

```
   \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[inner sep=0pt] (boy)  at (0,0)
{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{boy.jpg}};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (girl1) at (0,5)
{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{girl.jpg}};

\node[inner sep=0pt] (girl) at (0,10)
{\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{girl.jpg}};



%\draw[<->,thick] (boy) -- (girl1);
%
\node[inner sep=0pt] (pera) at (10,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{pera.png}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (grapes) at (10,5)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{grapes.png}};
%%\draw[<->,thick] (pera) -- (grapes)
   ;
\node[inner sep=0pt] (strawberry) at (10,10)
 {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{strawberry.png}};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (tangerine) at (10,15)
 {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{tangerine.png}};
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl1) -- (grapes);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl1) -- (strawberry);
\draw[-latex,thick] (girl1) -- (pera);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

New version:

[image]

Comment: What you try so far? including images in node should not be a problem (`\node[<style>] {\includegraphics[<size declaration>]{file name if image>};`),  so what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I am working on it. I'll provide you with a MWE in a few minutes.

Comment: The problem has to do with pointing the arrows!

Comment: for example `\draw (<source node name>.east) -- (<destination node name>);`  So far names of nodes you know only you. Provide MWE, that we can help you.

Comment: Hold on! I almost got it

Comment: I think that you have basically answered your down question now. Just add some colour to some of your arrows, a `dashed` to those you want dashed and then `\draw[red, latex-latex, thick](girl) to[out=210,in=150](boy);` for the curved arrow. If you want thicker lines then replace `thick` with `ultra thick`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since i haven't your image, i use option `demo` which instead your images produce black rectangles. I organized nodes in two chains (using library `chains`), distance between nodes are controlled by `node distance`. Nodes are named with names determined by chains (from `A-1` to `A-7`). Using those names enable set simple loops for drawing arrows between nodes.

For all nodes are defined common node style, the same is done for arrows (except first, which has arrow heads on both side).

For shorter code is used macro `Gin` from the `graphicx` package, by which is defined nodes' size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document remove option "demo"
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 4mm and 44mm,
      start chain = A going below,
every node/.style = {inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2mm, rounded corners,
                     text width=0.15\linewidth,
                     on chain=A},
        arr/.style = {color=#1, ultra thick, -{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}}
                        ]
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\node   {\includegraphics{boy.jpg}};    % A-1
\node   {\includegraphics{girl.jpg}};
\node   {\includegraphics{girl.jpg}};   % A-3
%
\node[above right=of A-1.east]
        {\includegraphics{pera.png}};         % A-4
\node   {\includegraphics{grapes.png}};
\node   {\includegraphics{strawberry.png}};
\node   {\includegraphics{tangerine.png}};    % A-7
%
\draw[red, ultra thick,
     {Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}-{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}
     ]  (A-1.west) to [bend right=45] (A-3.west);
\foreach \i in {4,...,7}
    \draw[arr=black] (A-1.east) -- (A-\i);
\draw[arr=blue!50!gray] (A-2.east) -- (A-5);
\foreach \i in {5,6}
    \draw[arr=purple!50!gray] (A-3.east) -- (A-\i);
%
\draw[arr=brown,densely dashed] (A-4) -- (A-3);
\draw[arr=brown,densely dashed] (A-7) -- (A-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to run your code! It looks great! A minor detail to change, check the last dashed arrow from tangerine to the boy. Maybe I can move it down?

Comment: you mean from "boy" to tangerine" ... since this arrow is determined in the loop, you need to chane destination coordinate for all nodes: `\draw[arr=black] (A-1.east) -- (A-\i.west);` or draw this line separately and reduce loop from `{4,....,7}` to `{4,...,6}`.

Comment: `\draw[arr=orange, ultra thick,dashed,
{}-{Straight Barb[angle=60:2pt 3]}
]  (A-7) to [bend left=45] (A-3);`